# QTikZ Save standalone TikZ file

Tags: tikz-pgf

In `QTikZ`, it is possible to export a `pdf`, `eps` and `png`.  I was wondering if it were possible to tell `QTikZ` to output a standalone `TikZ` file that is reading to add in a `LaTeX` document.  So basically, `QTikZ` would have to merge both the template and the `TikZ` image code into one file and save that.  I could do this manually, but I can't understand why this feature doesn't already exist.  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Also, if anyone has a suggestion for a better option to `QTikZ`, I'm open to suggestions; I'm using Ubuntu 13.

Comment: There is `tikzedt` that can do this. A linux edition is also available now. Link: http://www.tikzedt.org/

Comment: @user968243 did Harish's suggestion work for you, or is this question still open?

Comment: @HarishKumar Can you cook up an answer for this?

Comment: @percusse meals ready sir ;)

Answer (score 4):

[tikzedt](http://www.tikzedt.org)  offers some facility in this direction. You can chose to have a standalone file for the image. However, it doesn't use `standalone` document class. This should not be a big issue since the template can be easily altered.

[image]

Selecting `Insert full Code Sample` (on an empty source code window) will give

[image]

If you want to have `standalone` document class, go to `Settings` → `Settings`. In the window that opens choose `Compiler` tab. Now you can change the preamble.

[image]

But be careful not to mess up :)